# Convert string to int in c++ getting smaller value Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++

I am converting str = "355555555555555777777" to integer

```
int smallest;
stringstream(str) >> smallest;
```

I am getting smallest = -8795
I have tried atoi,_atoi64 and other ways but I am still getting lesser values.
The length of string is 35

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I have tried _int64 smallest, still the same error

Comment: First you need to find out what the max value of the data type you are trying to store the conversion is(look at `<limits>`), then you need to see if the string would be bigger than that.  If it is then you need to figure out how you want to handle that.

Comment: I had an array of char of length 30 which i converted to string then to int.

Comment: What @NathanOliver is getting at is that the string you want to convert represents a number larger than the maximum value that an int can store. You need to look at different data types to use instead of int than can handle such large numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The program behaviour is *undefined* since you are overflowing a signed integral type.

A 64 bit 1's or 2's complement `signed int` cannot be larger than 9223372036854775807. Your input number is larger than that.

If your system has `uint128_t`, you could try that. I'm deliberately using an `unsigned` type since the behaviour of overflowing an `unsigned` type **is** defined. If you don't have `uint128_t` then you'll have to use a library designed to handle large integers.

Comment: Which library do u suggest me to use?

Comment: Do you have the `uint128_t` type?

Comment: No i do not have that

Comment: Which compiler are you using? And do you need to target other platforms? If not then put the compiler in your question: other folk will then be able to answer your question.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2013

Comment: Have a look at boost multiprecision. It's a steep learning curve, but IMHO, worth the pain, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Failing that, upgrade your compiler to VS2015 if you are in control of your toolchain.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ big number library".